# X-Men: reading order for story arcs

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, suggested-order, story-arcs

I would like to confirm if this reading order for X-Men story arcs is correct. (For example, I've heard that “Messiah Complex” actually comes before “House of M”.)

Is the following reading order correct?

- The Dark Phoenix Saga
- Days of Future Past
- God Loves, Man Kills
- Mutant Massacre
- Fall of the Mutants
- Inferno
- Days of Future Present
- X-Tinction Agenda
- Muir Island Saga
- X-Cutioner Song
- Fatal Attractions
- Phalanx Covenant
- Age of Apocalypse
- Legion Quest
- Onslaught
- Children of the Atom
- Operation: Zero Tolerance
- The Twelve
- Dream's End
- Eve of Destruction
- E is for Extinction
- Riot at Xavier's
- Assault on Weapon Plus
- Planet X
- Here Comes Tomorrow
- Gifted
- House of M
- Decimation
- Unstoppable
- Deadly Genesis
- Rise and Fall of the Shi'ar Empire
- Endangered Species
- Messiah Complex
- Divided We Stand
- Manifest Destiny
- X-Infernus
- Messiah War
- Utopia
- Nation X
- Necrosha
- Second Coming
- Curse of the Mutants
- The Five Lights
- Age of X
- Schism
- Regenesis
- Avengers vs. X-Men

Source: [ComicVine Forum](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/x-men-155/order-of-major-story-arcs-724686/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've decided to try to order that list. I don't know if is the correct reading order, but I believe the most there is correct, maybe missing one or two titles too.

- *1979* - **Proteus**
- *1980* - **The Dark Phoenix Saga**
- *1981* - **Days of Future Past**
- *1982* - **God Loves, Man Kills**
- *1986* - **Mutant Massacre**
- *1988* - **Fall of the Mutants**
- *1989* - **Inferno**
- *1990* - **Days of Future Present**
- *1990* - **X-Tinction Agenda**
- *1991* - **Muir Island Saga**
- *1992* - **X-Cutioner Song**
- *1993* - **Fatal Attractions**
- *1993* - **Bloodties**
- *1994* - **Child's Play**
- *1994* - **Phalanx Covenant**
- *1995* - **Legion Quest**
- *1995* - **Age of Apocalypse**
- *1996* - **Onslaught Saga**
- *1997* - **Operation: Zero Tolerance**
- *1998* - **The Hunt for Xavier**
- *1999* - **Children of the Atom**
- *1999* - **The Magneto War**
- *2000* - **Apocalype: The Twelve**
- *2001* - **Dream's End**
- *2001* - **Eve of Destruction**
- *2001* - **E is for Extinction**
- *2003* - **Riot at Xavier's**
- *2003* - **Assault on Weapon Plus**
- *2004* - **Planet X**
- *2004* - **Gifted**
- *2005* - **Here Comes Tomorrow**
- *2005* - **House of M**
- *2005* - **Decimation** (spinning out of the events of the House of M
  limited series)
- *2005* - **X-Men: Deadly Genesis**
- *2006* - **Rise and Fall of the Shi'ar Empire**
- *2006* - **End of Greys**
- *2007* - **Unstoppable**
- *2007* - **Messiah Complex**
- *2008* - **X-Men: Endangered Species**
- *2008* - **X-Men: Manifest Destiny**
- *2008* - **X-Men: Divided We Stand**
- *2008* - **X-Infernus**
- *2008* - **Old Man Logan**
- *2009* - **X-Men: Quitting Time**
- *2009* - **Messiah War**
- *2009* - **Utopia**
- *2009* - **X-Men: Nation X**
- *2009* - **Necrosha**
- *2009* - **Second Coming**
- *2010* - **Curse of the Mutants**
- *2010* - **The Five Lights**
- *2011* - **Age of X**
- *2011* - **X-Men: Schism**
- *2011* - **X-Men: Regenesis**
- *2012* - **Avengers vs. X-Men**
- *2013* - **Battle of the Atom**
- *2013* - **X-Termination**
- *2014* - **Death of Wolverine**
- *2014* - **Avengers & X-Men: AXIS**
- *2014* - **The Trial of Jean Grey**
- *2015* - **The Black Vortex**
- *2016* - **Apocalypse Wars**